# How to set length of file write function call in lua?

Tags: lua

I'm using an embedded lua which provides an interface to access some data in C.
Specifically it gets an image blob in raw bytes.  I know the size of the raw data and I'm wanting to write this blob to disk.

However, I can't figure out from the lua io package how to write data of a set length.  How do I set the number of bytes that the write call will consume?

Comment: Uh, it writes exactly the amount of data you give it...

Comment: @immibis - had to solve it a completely different way.  Lua doesn't know how to write cdata

Answer (score 0):

The write functions of the io library expect a string or a number as input which both have a known length.

It's not like in C where you migh give a pointer and a number of bytes to be written.

Comment: Is there any way to convert it to a string given a length argument?  in luajit this would be easy, but...  it's not.

Comment: @Matt how do you get this data? as Userdata? Numbers?

Comment: userdata.  I think I might try writing a c module to handle it.  And then I can do jpeg encoding directly there instead.

Comment: @Matt yeah I guess that's a good idea. Lua is not particularly good at this binary stuff. I have to work in Lua and I don't have access to the C part of the parent application. At night I dream of being able to do simple bit operations ;-)

Comment: Yes, a "mutable binary chunk" as new standard Lua type (with all simple operations: create, setmetatable, read/write byte/word/dword/double at offset specified, add/sub/xor two chunks as big numbers, set/get length, convert to/from string/userdata, destroy_immediately without waiting for GC, lock_for_read/lock_exclusively/unlock for thread-safe work of several parallel Lua VMs with the same chunk) is my dream too.  With such type in Lua, we will not need C modules anymore for many simple tasks.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff :-D